# Capistrano, change host in task

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have the following problem:

I need to write capistrano task that will execute some commands on test_server_1 and then switch to test_server_2 for another set of commands.

I found out, I can do sth like:

```
task :test_task_for_test_server_1, roles: :test do
  run 'command 1'
  test_server_2
  run 'command 2'
end
```

command 1 will be executed on the test_server_1 and command 2 will be executed on both servers. I need to close session of test_server_1 and execute second command only on test_server_2. Any ideas if it's possible?

Comment: I would put them in separate tasks and roles and do `after :test_for_test_server_1, :test_for_test_server_2`  (but with more meaningful names.)

Comment: they share a variable, file name that is generated in the task

Comment: can you extract that to a separate method?

Comment: yes, but I don't know if this solve the problem. First task is doing a backup second restore. File name is a combination of server name and time stamp. Is it possible to call a capistrano task with parameter from other task?

Comment: I think you could just save it as an instance variable.
`def backup_filename  @backup_filename ||= server + timestanp; end` Then you could call that method from both tasks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```js
task :test_task_for_test_server_1, roles: :test do
  run 'command 1', :server => :test_server_1
  run 'command 2', :server => :test_server_2
end
```